# How to update select option elements in parent page after close popup register form page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two tables in Mysql: "autores" and "paises" (authors and countries) which are related by "id_pais":

```
CREATE TABLE `autores` (
  `id_autor` int NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `id_pais` int NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (`id_pais`) REFERENCES `paises` (`id_pais`)
);

CREATE TABLE `paises` (
  `id_pais` int NOT NULL,
  `pais` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

And two PHP pages for insert data in these tables: "registrar_autor.php" and "registrar_pais.php"

registrar_autor.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> REGISTRAR AUTOR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include("conexion.php");

        $sql_pais="SELECT * FROM paises";
        $resultado=$base->query($sql_pais);
        $registros=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);            
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Apellidos:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombres:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fecha de Nacimiento:</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="fecnac" id="fecnac"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>País</td>
            <td>
                <select name="pais" id="pais">
                    <?php 
                        foreach($registros as $pais):
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $pais->id_pais ?>"><?php echo $pais->pais ?></option>
                    <?php
                        endforeach;
                    ?>
                </select>
                <a href="registrar_pais.php" target='popup' onclick="window.open('registrar_pais.php','popup','width=600;height=600'); return false">Registrar nuevo país</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Cancelar"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="agregar" id="agregar" value="Agregar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Registrar_pais.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>REGISTRAR PAÍS</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <?php
        include("conexion.php");
        
        if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
            $pais=$_POST['pais'];

            $insercion="INSERT INTO paises(pais) VALUES (:p_pais)";
            $result=$base->prepare($insercion);
            $result->execute(array(":p_pais"=>$pais));
            
        ?>

        <script>
            if (window.opener != null) 
            {
                window.close();
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        </script>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="agregar" id="agregar" value="Agregar">
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is "conexion.php", the database connection file:

```
<?php

    try{
        $base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=biblioteca','root','root2021');
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
    }
    catch(Exception $ex){
        die('Error ' -$ex->getMessage());
        echo "Línea del error".$ex->getLine();
    }

?>
```

In "registrar_autor.php", it may be the case that the country of the author to be registered is not in the select option, for which I programmed the "registrar_pais.php" to open in a popup, and then I want that when registering a new country, the popup is closed (I already achieved that) and that in the page "registrar_autor.php" the select option is automatically updated with the new country loaded, without affecting the values written in the other input text. How could I achieve that? With Javascript? Jquery? Please help me

[image: registrar_autor.php]

[image: registrar_libro.php]

Comment: Your question has *absolutely nothing* to do with database or mysql. Whatever automatic update is done by means of *javascript*

Comment: Please, give me a solution.